# How to use alarm in Android Pie

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

i'm making an app for events and users can set alerts to the events they want. I use the AlarmManager for this, and the problem is on Android 9(Pie), that it seems blocking alarms and the notifications is not showing anymore.
For Android <= 8 there aren't problems.
Any tip/solution here?
Thanks

Comment: Use JobScheduler instead of AlarmManager

Comment: @sm_ i can't use JobScheduler because i need to schedule notification at an exact time

Answer (score 0):

Alarms do not fire when the device is idle in [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). Any scheduled alarms will be deferred until the device exits Doze. If you need to ensure that your work completes even when the device is idle there are several options available. You can use [setAndAllowWhileIdle() or [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to guarantee that the alarms will execute. Another option is to use the new [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/arch/work), which is built to perform background work either once or periodically. For more information, see Schedule tasks with [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/arch/work).](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Ref: [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms).

Comment: Uh thanks! I'll try setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()...
I've searched for workmanager, but it seems they can't run at an exact time, am i right?